# Position not at the right position

Tags: react-leaflet

Previously i have made a map for a game in vanilla js (it work well)
I have try to migrate the map on react-leaflet, but i have some issues with the position.
I have a custom image overlay, and world game position translated to leaflet position.

```
 worldToMapImgX(worldX) {
    return (worldX + 234002.2054794521) / 241.041095890411;
}

worldToMapImgY(worldY) {
    return 1943 - (worldY + 231101.3928571428) / 242.5535714285714;
}

mapImgToWorldX(mapDivX) {
    return 241.041095890411 * mapDivX - 234002.2054794521;
}

mapImgToWorldY(mapDivY) {
    return 242.5535714285714 * (1943 - mapDivY) - 231101.3928571428;
}
```

Its pure vanilla javascript with leaflet.js it work.
But when i try to put a marker or set the center of the map, the position is wrong.

This is my react component

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { UIWindow } from "../../components";
import assets from "../../assets";
import * as React from "react";
import constants from "../../actions/constants";
import { Map, ImageOverlay, Marker, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet'
import { CRS, Icon } from "leaflet";

class GameMap extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            position: [this.worldToMapImgY(-61822), this.worldToMapImgX(-55196)],
            icons: this.setupIcons()
        }
    }

    setupIcons() {
        let icons = {};
        for(let i in assets.gamemap) {
            icons[i] = new Icon({
                iconUrl: assets.gamemap[i],
                iconSize: [25, 25],
                iconAnchor: [12, 12],
                shadowSize: [0, 0]
            })
        }
        return icons;
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    componentWillUnmount() {

    }

    worldToMapImgX(worldX) {
        return (worldX + 234002.2054794521) / 241.041095890411;
    }

    worldToMapImgY(worldY) {
        return 1943 - (worldY + 231101.3928571428) / 242.5535714285714;
    }

    mapImgToWorldX(mapDivX) {
        return 241.041095890411 * mapDivX - 234002.2054794521;
    }

    mapImgToWorldY(mapDivY) {
        return 242.5535714285714 * (1943 - mapDivY) - 231101.3928571428;
    }

    render() {
        return <Map _ref={e => console.log(e)} center={this.state.position} zoom={0} minZoom={-10} crs={CRS.Simple} zoomControl={false} zoomAnimation={true}>
            <ImageOverlay url={assets.gamemap.map} bounds={[[0,0], [1943,2000]]}>
                <Marker position={this.state.position} icon={this.state.icons["icon_lumberjack"]} />
            </ImageOverlay>
        </Map>
    }
}
```

This is a picture of the map, the marker should be displayed in the north west of the map

GameMap:
  [image]

Thank for your help :)

Comment: `ImageOverlay` does not have a `children` props, check [here](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/src/ImageOverlay.js) that means you cannot place `Marker` as a child. Moreover, `<Map _ref` should be `<Map ref`